# Call Javascript on link click through htmltextwriter

Tags: c#, javascript

```
...
... 
HtmlTextWriter write12 = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
...
...
write12.AddAttribute("href", myURL);
write12.WriteEncodedText("Click here to redirect");
...
...
```

- The above code was working fine, but i want to redirect and display in pop up window.
- So is it possible to call a javascript on click of the link.

Comment: Sure, add an `onclick` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Did i understand correctly that you want to open the link in a new window ?

You can do this by setting the target to `_blank`

Like this, not tested at all:

```
HtmlTextWriter write12 = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);


write12.AddAttribute("href", myURL);
write12.AddAttribute("target", "_blank");
write12.WriteEncodedText("Click here to redirect");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `onclick` attribute :

```
write12.AddAttribute("onclick", "JsFunction()");
```

Javascript

```
function JsFunction()
{
  // open popup
  // ...
}
```